# Parse API Limit/requests and reporting on Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, rate-limiting

We are building a new application in parse and are trying to estimate our requests/second and optimize the application to limit it and keep it below the 30/second.   Our app, still in development, makes various calls to parse.   Some only use 1 requests, and a few as many as 5 requests.    We have tested and verified this in the analytics/events/api requests tab.

However, when I go to the analytics/performance/total requests section, the requests/second rarely go above .2 and are often much lower.   I assume this is because this is an average over a minute or more.   So I have two questions:

1) does anyone know what the # represents on this total requests/second screen.  Is it an average over a certain time period.   If so, how much?

2) when parse denies the request due to rate limit, does it deny based on the actual per second, or is it based on an average over a certain time period?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I supposed you have your answer by now but just in case:

You're allowed 30reqs/sec on a free plan, but Parse actually counts it on a per minute basis, or 1800 requests per minute.